# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I am using `Retro Fit` to connect to API online. But I am getting this error while trying to parse the returned data.

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

The data being returned is in [This](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging) format and model for data is also given below:

```
iGPlaceApi.getStreams(ITEMS_PER_PAGE, pageNumber * ITEMS_PER_PAGE, new Callback<List<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>>() {

            @Override
            public void success(List<mGooglePlacesApiResponse> mGp, Response response) {
                int n = mGp.size();
                Object asa = mGp.toArray();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                String error = retrofitError.toString();
            }
        });

public class mGooglePlacesApiResponse {

    public String html_attributions;
    //public List<String> html_attributions;
    public String next_page_token;
    public List<place> results;
}

public class place {

    public Geometry geometry;
    public String icon;
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public OpeningHours opening_hours;
    public List<Photo> photo
    ...
```

Comment: your json starts with jsonarray?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `List<mGooglePlacesApiResponse> mGp` to `mGooglePlacesApiResponse mGp`. Your JSON contains object not list.

@edit

Btw, html_attributions is an array

@edit2

Well, i see you corrected your html_attrubutions